# Export Oracle table to New Excel Document

Tags: c#, excel, oracle

I am trying to build code to run on a SQL Server Agent that will export Oracle tables and put them into a new Excel product automatically. What is the best method and could someone provide step by step instructions on writing the code?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about "best", but I have done this by saving a CSV file with a ".xls" file type. Windows thinks its Excel, opens it with Excel, and the CSV is automatically turned into a spread sheet.

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server Agent to export Oracle tables?  This depends if its a one-off or not, there are many ways to achieve this